# Salvar entidade e todas as suas entidades filhas

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

Estou com problemas nos updates da minha entidade MDFe, antes de explicar o que acontece, gostaria que olhassem a imagem abaixo, a partir dela poderei explicar melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podemos verificar que O MDFe tem uma relação de um para muitos com  MDFeDocumento cujo este também tem uma relação de um para muitos com a MDFeUnidadeTransporte e esta possui uma relação de um para muitos com a MDFeUnidadeCarga.

O CRUD desta estrutura é realizado todo sobre o MDFe.
Ao editar um mdfe e dar update na entidade, o mdfeDocumento é alterado, porem, a partir dai, as demais entidades não sofrem as alterações.
Por exemplo: Se ao editar um MDFe e alterar a unidade de transporte de um determinado documento, ao dar o update na entidade MDFe, a unidade de transporte não sofre a alteração realizada.

Como posso fazer com que essas inserções/alterações sejam realizadas somente salvando o MDFe?
Caso não é possível inserir/update apenas a entidade pai, qual o melhor jeito de insert/update as demais?

Obrigado a todos, e se tiverem dúvidas em minha explicação comentem que eu vou melhorando.

Answer (score 0):

Gilvan se vc estiver usando JPA fica facil, é so usar a anotação

> cascadeType.ALL

no list das suas entidades. Por exemplo:

A classe MDFe provavelmente tem uma lista de MDFeDocumento, nessa lista coloque a anotação citada acima.

```
public class MDFe{

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   protected List<MDFeDocumento> userAddresses;

}
```

ou no FetchType coloque eager

```
public class MDFe{

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   protected List<MDFeDocumento> userAddresses;

}
```

assim por diante, sua classe MDFeDocumento deve ter uma lista de MDFeUnidadeTransporte com essa anotação e isso se estende ate onde vc quiser.
Ao salvar o MDFe todo resto sera salvo.